# What is the point of LongLength Property in Array class in c#?

Tags: c#

I know someone asked this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332874/what-is-the-purpose-of-longlength-for-net-arrays)
but it still doesn't make any sense for such a property! I looked into the source code of the Array class on [GitHub here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/array.cs) As you can see from source code, all methods related to finding a specific index, for example:

```
public static int LastIndexOf<T>(T[] array, T value)
```

return integer value `System.Int32`, So again, What is the point of a property which returns a `System.Int64` representation of an array length but all the other methods that deal with internal item indices return `System.Int32`? This is really confusing!

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate you may have several dimensions that are all reflected in `LongLength`. It´s not hard to think of an array of 1000x1000x1000 elements.

Comment: I see, each dimension has an integer length, but all dimensions may have a `System.Int64` length. Thanks, I didn't think about that scenario, and I didn't get it from the selected answer or all the other answers in this question
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: both `Length` and `LongLength` return the [total number of elements in all the dimensions of the array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx). given that there is a [hardcoded limitation in the Microsoft implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,624) of `Array` of 0x7FEFFFFF bytes in the current framework libraries (and [other parts of that implementation rely on that](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/ThreadLocal.cs,591)...), this is probably something only the devs can answer.

Comment: @dlatikay, I see. Thanks, I didn't know that! This is a real surprise! Why they didn't make the Length property type a generic type? or better, making a separate method called `GetAllDimensionLength()` which returns `System.Int64`. Do you think it's a good idea to propose?

Comment: If you need to use `LongLength` you may also need to set this config setting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcallowverylargeobjects-element .